# readline: How do I change keymaps from `emacs` to `vi-command` with a binding?

Tags: bash, readline

In bash (4.3.11(1)-release), I want to be able to change straight from `emacs` keymap to the `vi-command` keymap.

With `show-mode-in-prompt on`, my prefix character should change from `@` to `:`.

If I use the `vi-movement-mode` command, the prompt stays as `@`.

If I use the `vi-editing-mode` command, the prompt changes to `+` indicating I'm using the `vi-insert` keymap, rather than the desired target `vi-command`.

How do I change from `emacs` to `vi-command` keymaps via a binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following `.inputrc` lines allow <kbd>Meta / Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to toggle between `emacs` and `vi-insert` modes.

Mooshing both <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> simultaneously will take you to `vi-command` mode.

```
set show-mode-in-prompt on

set keymap emacs
"\ee": vi-editing-mode
"jk": "\eejk"
"kj": "\eejk"

set keymap vi-insert
"\ee": emacs-editing-mode
"jk": vi-movement-mode
"kj": vi-movement-mode

set keymap vi-command
"\ee": emacs-editing-mode
```

Note: The only English word with "kj" is "blackjack", no words contain "jk")

Note: In `bash` v4.3.11(1), if you add a binding under `keymap emacs` to `vi-movement-mode` to try to switch straight to the `vi-command` keymap, the prompt doesn't update if you have `show-mode-in-prompt on`, hence this work-around is needed.