# Bash Process Substitution Hangs When Listing Bindings

Tags: bash, osx, background-process, freeze, process-substitution

**TLDR:**

```
cat <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs') # freezes

# I can't use this because I need to pipe the output of the bind
cat <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs' &) # doesn't freeze

# I can use this. This won't work for comm below since it takes two file inputs.
cat < <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs') # doesn't freeze

# I can use this.
cat <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs') & fg # doesn't freeze

# I can use this. This is my current solution
cat <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs') | cat # doesn't freeze
```

Why does it freeze and why does backgrounding fix it? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837546/bash-process-substitution-hangs-for-script-output) says it has something to do with `EOF`, so it would be waiting on `stdin`. Is there a way to inject an `EOF`? And why would it be missing an `EOF`?

---

I don't know if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong.

I using bash-4.4.12(1)-release on macOS but I tested using `gnu-grep` and `gnu-sort` on and got the same results.

I am trying to compare the default bindings of bash using process substitution so I don't have to create extra files.

This is how I am getting the default bindings for emacs. I run a bash command with an empty `INPUTRC`. The `grep` is to remove unneeded bindings and the `sort` is so i can compare these `emacs` bindings with the `vi` ones using `comm` later.
I got this command from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303479/what-are-readlines-modes-keymaps-and-their-default-bindings).

```
INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs' |
LC_ALL='C' grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' |
sort
```

Similarly, here's how to get the default `vi-insert` bindings. Just replace `emacs` with `vi-insert`

```
INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm vi-insert' |
LC_ALL='C' grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' |
sort
```

Okay now I want to compare these two with `comm` so I wrap those two commands with process substitution and run `comm` on them.

```
comm \
  <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs' |
    LC_ALL='C' grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' |
    sort) \
  <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm vi-insert' |
    LC_ALL='C' grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' |
    sort)
```

output:

```
bash: line 0: bind: warning: line editing not enabled
bash: line 0: bind: warning: line editing not enabled
... (empty. I have to press CTRL+C to exit)
```

To keep it simple for now, this also freezes

```
cat <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs')
```

So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837546/bash-process-substitution-hangs-for-script-output) which says backgrounding with `&` helps, and it does work.

```
cat <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs' &) # works, has output, no freeze
```

So now I try to apply this knowledge to the original command but I can't because there's a pipe.

```
...'bind -pm emacs' &|... # doesn't work
...'bind -pm emacs' |&... # doesn't work, this is for redirecting stderr to stdout
```

So then I try backgrounding the whole thing entirely. Append `&` at the very end of that long command. `fg` it immediately to keep it a one line command. This works

```
comm \
  <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs' |
    LC_ALL='C' grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' |
    sort) \
  <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm vi-insert' |
    LC_ALL='C' grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' |
    sort) & fg
```

Piping to cat also fixes it

```
comm \
  <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs' |
    LC_ALL='C' grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' |
    sort) \
  <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm vi-insert' |
    LC_ALL='C' grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' |
    sort) | cat
```

I noticed that when I try closing the terminal with the freezing command, those processes are still running. So CTRL+C doesn't stop those commands
[image]

Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: I have a weird suggestion: what happens if you extend the command you're passing to `bash -c` to be `'bind -pm whatever; true'`?

Comment: Looks like I get the same results. `cat <(INPUTRC=/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs; true')` freezes. Also freezes in the giant `comm` command when you do `bash -c 'bind -pm emacs; true'` and `bash -c 'bind -pm vi-insert; true'` in file1 and file2 respectively.

Comment: Okay, next question: why use `bash -c` at all?  What's wrong with `INPUTRC=/dev/null bind -pm emacs | whatever`?

Comment: The goal of setting `INPUTRC` to `/dev/null` is to get the default bindings of the shell, ignoring my current bindings.
You get different results with that command. `bash` uses `readline` which reads the file specified by `INPUTRC` (defaults to `~/.inputrc` if unset) on startup.
If you don't start bash, `INPUTRC` is not reread.
You can use `bind -f` to read keybindings from a file. But that doesn't unbind keys that were applied after the defaults and reads bindings into the current shell.

Comment: This must be a macOS thing. In debian this works even without piping to `cat`.